# Power automate: list tasks from planner, and populate a table with tasks data, including multiple assignees for a task in to a single column

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-planner

[image]I am creating in power automate a flow to collect Planner data.
I have hundreads of tasks and those tasks are assigned to multiple people (same task can have multiple assignees).

I am doing the following steps:
1 - List rows present in a table
2 - Apply to each: delete row (so i can clean the table to update all the data)
3 - list tasks from planner
4 - Apply to each value: add a row into a table.

I am failing on the step 4 when I try to get assignees. I can add all other data to my table, but assignees.

How can I collect all assignees from a taks and store in a single column in my table, for each name separated with ";"?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: The question doesn't make the problem clear. If you can share the flow and the error you have, and the error you are getting it would allow people to find a solution.